# SQL sum 12 weeks of data based on first sold date across different items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, rolling-sum

The database has thousands of individual items, each with multiple first sold dates and sales results by week. I need a total sum for each products first 12 weeks of sales.

Code was used for previous individual queries when we know the start date using a SUM(CASE. This is too manual though with thousands of products to review and we are looking for a smart way to speed this up.

Can I build on this so the sum find the minimum first shop date, and then  sums the next 12 weeks of results? If so, how do I structure it, or is there a better way?

Columns in database I will need to reference with sample data

PROD_ID | WEEK_ID | STORE_ID | FIRST_SHOP_DATE | ITM_VALUE

12345543 | 201607 | 10000001 | 201542 | 24,356

12345543 | 201607 | 10000002 | 201544 | 27,356

12345543 | 201608 | 10000001 | 201542 | 24,356

12345543 | 201608 | 10000002 | 201544 | 27,356

32655644 | 201607 | 10000001 | 201412 | 103,245

32655644 | 201607 | 10000002 | 201420 | 123,458

32655644 | 201608 | 10000001 | 201412 | 154,867

32655644 | 201608 | 10000002 | 201420 | 127,865

Comment: 1)tag the dbms being used.2)show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text. Tag the dbms you're using. Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Thanks, added sample data and DBMS tag

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
select itemid, sum(sales)
from (select t.*, min(shopdate) over (partition by itemid) as first_shopdate
      from t
     ) t
where shopdate < first_stopdate + interval '84' day
group by id;
```

You don't specify the database, so this uses ANSI standard syntax.  The date operations (in particular) vary by database.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Kirsty, Try like this -**

```
select a.Item,sum(sales) as totla
from tableName a JOIN
(select Item, min(FirstSoldDate) as FirstSoldDate from tableName group by item) b
ON a.Item = b.Item
where a.FirstSoldDate between b.FirstSoldDate and (dateadd(day,84,b.FirstSoldDate))
group by a.Item
```

Thanks :)